# Game doesn't stop from event-loop

Tags: python, pygame

I got this far and it kind of got all confusing and I can't figure out one simple problem with the code.

```
while not gameExit:
    while gameOver == True:
        pygame.display.flip()
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        display_message("OVER. C to continue, Q to quit", red)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    gameOver = False
                    gameExit = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    gameLoop()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type  == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x_change = -10
                lead_y_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x_change = 10
                lead_y_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                lead_y_change = -10
                lead_x_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                lead_y_change = 10
                lead_x_change = 0
        if  ( lead_x < 0 ) or (lead_x >= 600) or ( lead_y < 0 ) or ( lead_y >= 800):
            gameOver = True
```

So when I run this code, and when the snake goes over the boundary, the C for continue and Q for quit thing doesn't come **UNTIL** I press a button on the keyboard or move my mouse. Why is that?

Comment: Have you already fixed the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Move:

```
if  ( lead_x < 0 ) or (lead_x >= 600) or ( lead_y < 0 ) or ( lead_y >= 800):
        gameOver = True
```

out of the `pygame.event.get`-loop because it will only run if events have taken place (mouse moved, key pressed). Otherwise the code will not reach the check without your action.